# GitBash VisualStudio Solution gitignore

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gitignore, projects-and-solutions, git-bash, gitattributes

I deleted gitignore and gitattributes files and used gitbash to `-f` commit everything and it put the `obj`, `debug`, etc files I don't want. So i want to recommit everything but also want the git ignore rules to be inforced.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to recommit everything

Simply (in commandline) do a:

```
git reset @~
```

That will reset `HEAD` to the previous commit, allowing you to re-add and commit what you want.

> I deleted `gitignore` and `gitattributes` files

Restore at least the `.gitignore` file if you want `gitignore` rules to be enforced:

```
git checkout -- .gitignore
```